# ngFor won't render accessible data. When I try it breaks my code. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using *ngFOr to Interpolate through data. Everything seems fine on the surface, till i try accessing data nested in an object inside an object.

for instance

```
{
  "tvshow": [
    {
      "id": "value",
      "time": {
        "clock": "value",
        "material": {
          "type": "value"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let tvshow of tvshow">
{{tvshow.id}}
{{tvshow.time.clock}} - Works
{{tvshow.time.material}} - prints out [object Object] as it should
{{tvshow.time.material.type}} - Does not work. And breaks the whole page. Makes no sense.
</div>
```

Anyone else came across that issue at some point ? This literally make no sense to me.

Comment: it should be `tvshow[0].time.material.type`

Comment: Not a chance. The problem is not at the start, it's at the end.

Comment: @Navitas28 It sure is not. Did you check the question ? Everything works but the last option. Would be pointless to index the array.

Comment: See its works correctly [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwmu6t?file=src%2Fmain.ts) the problem is your are iterating over something which is not present

Comment: `let tvshow of tvshow` - Don't use the same variable name as what the array is.

Comment: Try adding a safe navigation operator to rule out possible causes: {{tvshow?.time?.material?.type}}

Comment: It does not make sence for your example, but if an other data set does not have material or time it will break the whole page. So try with safe navigation operator like said by De wet van As

Comment: @Navitas28 It is present in the json file. Hence the reason {{tvshow.time.material}} - prints out [object Object] as it should .

Comment: @YongShun . That was just an example. I have it done properly.

Comment: @DeWetvanAs Your option works properly . Thanks. WHy is that so ?

Comment: @allforthenoob it is most likely that one of the items in your array does not have all the values. This will effectively cause a null reference error and cause the rendering to break.

Comment: @DeWetvanAs That is absolute true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely that one of the items in your array does not have all the values. This will effectively cause a null reference error and cause the rendering to break.

Use the safe navigation operator to prevent rendering errors where the null values exist:

```
{{tvshow?.time?.material?.type}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @DeWetvanAs for the answer in the comments.

> It is most likely that one of the items in your array does not have
> all the values. This will effectively cause a null reference error and
> cause the rendering to break.

–
De Wet van As

That was actually the issue and the use of the safe navigation operator (?) fixed the problem.
{{tvshow?.time?.material?.type}}